# Select option by value jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find the option inside an select by value. The select Input is already a jquery object. This is my code so far:

```
my_select.filter("option[value='2']").attr('selected', "selected");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
my_select.find("option[value='2']").prop('selected', "selected");
```

Comment: @tliokos It should be `.prop('selected', true)` instead of `.prop('selected', "selected")`. But using `.prop` instead of `.attr` is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the value, try

```
my_select.val(2);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AfLtG/2/)

Comment: Since sometimes jQuery does different things depending on the type, passing `'2'` could be safer than `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` instead of `filter()`:

```
my_select.find("option[value='2']").prop('selected', true);
```

It's also better to use `prop()` than `attr()`

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enQ63/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use **find** instead of **filter** then your code will work as your required.