# undefined value for data-set

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to have value of data-set with JQuery, but it returns undefined value and I don't know why:

```
<option class="option" 
        value="<?php echo $art["id_art"]; ?>"
        data-unite="<?php echo $art["unite_lib"]; ?>" 
        data-qte="<?php echo $art["art_solde"]; ?>"
        data-perissables="<?php echo $art["perissable"]; ?>">
    <?php echo $art["lib_art"]. " périssable : ".$art["perissable"]; ?>
</option>
```

and with JS :

```
var id = $(this).find("option").val()
var qte = $(`option[value=${id}]`).data("qte");
var perissable = $(`option[value=${id}]`).attr("data-perissables")
console.log(perissable);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your javascript as presented.  You can get the value (though calling it `id` is just confusing) and find option using template literals: https://jsfiddle.net/uq7464up/   But the two finds give the same option as `$(this).find("option")` - so are pointless as presented.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272058/select-option-by-value-jquery.

Comment: What browser are you using? If it's IE11 then you can't use template literals the text inside backticks:  https://caniuse.com/#search=template

Comment: Does your output html actually have values?  You've provided with the php hieroglyphics - can you provide with the rendered output?

Comment: Can you include where you're calling your JS from?  Use of `this` implies a `select` change event, but if it's a button, then it will have the wrong context.

Comment: Also, change your console.log to `console.log(id, qte, perissable`)` is `id` also output as undefined?

Comment: no only the perissable output undefined

Answer (score 0):

I tested all your proposals, maybe I did not ask my question 
 in fact the data of the selectbox comes from my database and for each value i try to have value of "perissable".

```
<?php foreach($articles as $art): ?>
                                                        <?php if($art["id_type_art"] == "1"): ?>
                                                             <?php  if(!in_array($art["id_art"],$tab) ):    ?>
                                                                <option class="option" value="<?php echo $art["id_art"]; ?>" data-unite="<?php echo $art["unite_lib"]; ?>" data-qte="<?php echo $art["art_solde"]; ?>" data-perissables="<?php echo $art["perissable"]; ?>"><?php echo $art["lib_art"]; ?></option>
                                                                <?php $tab[]= $art["id_art"] ; ?>
                                                             <?php endif ?>

                                                        <?php endif ?>

                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you should edit your question and add this as an edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your jqyery code, and in this line:

```
var id = $(this).find("option").val()
```

The result (id) is `undefined`. But I changed `$(this)` to `$('body')` and it worked. In your code `$(this)` is equal to `window` . Change your first jquery line to this:

```
var id = $('body').find("option").val()
```

Update:

If your codes are about a select box change or click event you can do this easily:

```
var qte = $(this).data("qte");
var perissable = $(this).attr("data-perissables")
```

Comment: but when i try it i don't have the correct id. but when do this var id = $(this).val()  i get the correct id but the result of perissable is undefined

Comment: but I see that it is on one option that it does not work. for others I recover the value of "perissable"

Comment: Where you locate your jquery codes? Please test this just beside of your codes: `console.log($(this))` and read the result in console.

Comment: And please remember that `var id = $('body').find("option").val()` will give you the value of the first `option` in your page and `$(this)` could have different values on different locations.

Comment: yes var id = $('body').find("option").val() give value of the first option, but i want to have of each option when i select one element in my selctbox so $(this).val() do it correctly

Comment: when i do console.log($(this)) it return the selectbox option

Comment: Ok. So your code probably is on `select` changing event or some thing like. It was better you have written your code more complete.

Comment: In this case `$(this).val()` is exactly what you want. The value of the selected option.

Comment: the value of the option is not the problem i get it, but the value of data-perissable is undefined that is the problem

Comment: Maybe your problem is here: `data-perissables="<?php echo $art["perissable"]; ?>">` you have a bad closing tag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I saw what was causing the problem. in fact there was a confusion with the datatable paggination options. so I proceeded like that to properly target the element.

```
$("#select-articles").on("change", function(e){
                var id = $(this).val()
                var qte = $(`option[value=${id}]`).data("qte");
                var perissable = $(this).find(`option[value=${id}]`).data("perissable");
                var url = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/Articles/get_cout_date_exp/"); ?>'})
```